# How to Extract Top Words from K-Means Clusters Using Scikit?

Tags: python, k-means, feature-extraction

I'm currently using K-means clustering on text data (marketing activity descriptions) vectorized by tf-idf, and have an elbow-informed optional k, have made a scatterplot using PCA, and have added a column with cluster labels to my data frame (all in python). So in one sense I can interpret my clustering model by reviewing the labeled text data.

However, I would like to also be able to extract N most frequent words from each of the clusters.

First I'm reading in the data and getting an optimal k via elbow:

```html
# import pandas to use dataframes and handle tabular data, e.g the labeled text dataset for clustering
import pandas as pd

# read in the data using panda's "read_csv" function
col_list = ["DOC_ID", "TEXT", "CODE"]
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/williammarcellino/Downloads/AEMO_Sample.csv', usecols=col_list, encoding='latin-1')

# use regular expression to clean annoying "/n" newline characters
data = data.replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True) 

#import sklearn for TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# vectorize text in the df and fit the TEXT data. Builds a vocabulary (a python dict) to map most frequent words 
# to features indices and compute word occurrence frequency (sparse matrix). Word frequencies are then reweighted 
# using the Inverse Document Frequency (IDF) vector collected feature-wise over the corpus.
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words={'english'})
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data.TEXT)

#use elbow method to determine optimal "K"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
Sum_of_squared_distances = []
# we'll try a range of K values, use sum of squared means on new observations to deteremine new centriods (clusters) or not
K = range(6,16)
for k in K:
   km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=200, n_init=10)
   km = km.fit(X)
   Sum_of_squared_distances.append(km.inertia_)
plt.plot(K, Sum_of_squared_distances, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Sum_of_squared_distances')
plt.title('Elbow Method For Optimal k')
plt.show()
```

Based on that, I build a model at k=9:

```html
# optimal "K" value from elobow plot above
true_k = 9

# define an unsupervised clustering "model" using KMeans
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10)

#fit model to data
model.fit(X)

# define clusters lables (which are integers--a human needs to make them interpretable)
labels=model.labels_
title=[data.DOC_ID]

#make a "clustered" version of the dataframe
data_cl=data

# add label values as a new column, "Cluster"
data_cl['Cluster'] = labels

# I used this to look at my output on a small sample; remove for large datasets in actual analyses
print(data_cl)

# output our new, clustered dataframe to a csv file
data_cl.to_csv('/Users/me/Downloads/AEMO_Sample_clustered.csv')
```

Finally I plot the principle components:

```html
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
  
model_indices = model.fit_predict(X)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
scatter_plot_points = pca.fit_transform(X.toarray())

colors = ["r", "b", "c", "y", "m", "paleturquoise", "g", 'aquamarine', 'tab:orange']

x_axis = [o[0] for o in scatter_plot_points]
y_axis = [o[1] for o in scatter_plot_points]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))


ax.scatter(x_axis, y_axis, c=[colors[d] for d in model_indices])


for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x_axis[i]+.005, y_axis[i]), size=10)
```

Any help extracting and plotting top terms from each cluster would be a great help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my question by using code found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-clustering-8e1e64c1561c).

```html
def get_top_features_cluster(tf_idf_array, prediction, n_feats):
    prediction = km.predict(scatter_plot_points)
    labels = np.unique(prediction)
    dfs = []
    for label in labels:
        id_temp = np.where(prediction==label) # indices for each cluster
        x_means = np.mean(tf_idf_array[id_temp], axis = 0) # returns average score across cluster
        sorted_means = np.argsort(x_means)[::-1][:n_feats] # indices with top 20 scores
        features = tf_idf_vectorizor.get_feature_names()
        best_features = [(features[i], x_means[i]) for i in sorted_means]
        df = pd.DataFrame(best_features, columns = ['features', 'score'])
        dfs.append(df)
    return dfs
dfs = get_top_features_cluster(tf_idf_array, prediction, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is not working for me, so I did something like:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dfi['text'][~dfi['text'].isna()])

print('How many clusters do you want to use?')
true_k = int(input())
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=200, n_init=10)
model.fit(X)

labels=model.labels_
clusters=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(dfi['text'][~dfi['text'].isna()],labels)),columns=['title','cluster'])

features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
n_feats=15
for i in range(true_k):
    cclust=X[clusters['cluster'] == i]
    meanWts=cclust.A.mean(axis=0)
    sorted_mean_ix = np.argsort(meanWts)[::-1][:n_feats] # indices with top 15 scores

    #get most important feature names:
    print(np.array(features)[sorted_mean_ix])
```